# Notification at end of CountDownTimer

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make notification to tell me that my `CountDownTimer` has ended, But im having some trouble. At the moment i have established just a test notification (i think) But i don't know how to call for the notification to work. Here is what i have at the moment:

```
public void onFinish() {
      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(TestTimer.this);
      mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
      mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");
     TextView timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    timer.setText("Seconds remaining: 0 ")
```

This is called once the timer = 0, and i want to know if its possible to call for a notification when it does.

Thanks in advance for any help, If you need any more code feel free to ask.

Comment: The builder needs a `PendingIntent` set via `setContentIntent` and then use the `NotificationManager`'s `notify` method to send the notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable notification you need to call `PendingIntent` so notification will work.

try this in your `onFinish`

```
 public void onFinish() {
                 NotificationManager  notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                 Notification  myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
                    String notificationText = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0,   myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);
                    myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationText, pendingIntent);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
             }
```

Comment: It is worth nothing that in the `notify` command, the "1" in the code above indicates the message id.  Changing that will allow multiple messages to be posted whereas keeping it the same overwrites the previous notification's information.